# FA icons do not appear in second page of my html project. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I am making a project with multiple html pages. Currently I have "index.html" and "addAccount.html," whenever I try to add a link to the head of the second file, it is not underlined and does not appear in blue. As such, I included this in the head:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

to gain access to the fa icons but for some reason, I can only include the fa icons that I have already included in my other page in this one (for example, I used `<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>` in "index.html" and I can use it in "addAccount.html", but I cannot use any other icon - even the free ones - in "addAccount.html"). What I missing? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the script before using it. Also, you need to classify what is the type you're refering: *brand - regular - solid*

In this example, I've tried with *solid* style (notice the `s` character): `fas fa-caret-down`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>

<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
```